# Year to month date conversion

Tags: datetime, stata, stata-macros

I have a dataset in wide format that has quarterly counts of an event from `Q1` `1996` to `Q4` `2016`.

The variable names for each quarter are as follows:

- Q1 = `yyyy0101_yyyy0401`
- Q2 = `yyyy0401_yyyy0701`
- Q3 = `yyyy0701_yyyy1001`
- Q4 = `yyyy1001_yyyy0101`

I have a macro that converts them like this:

```
local i = 1996

forvalues x = 1996/2016 { 
    local i = `i'+1
    gen count`x' = event_`x'0101_`x'0401 + event_`x'0401_`x'0701 + 
    event_`x'0701_`x'1001 + event_`x'1001_`i'0101
}
```

Then I collapse my data into a single variable `count` in long format by year:

```
reshape long count, i(xvars) j(year)
```

Now I would like to do the same thing, but quarterly.

What is the macro to perform the exact same process, but capturing the sum of counts by year-quarter? What if I wanted to do it for half years?

Comment: I have left the title more or less as it was, but it doesn't bear any obvious relation to the problem. (A personal and I think forum principle is to edit presentation only for grammar, spelling, syntax, style and other presentation errors and weaknesses but to leave substantive errors and obscurities as posted.) The answer comments on the non-Stata sense of macro, which naturally is incidental to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In trying to understand this I note first (pedantically, or otherwise) that your code is not a macro in Stata's sense: SAS user???) and second (more constructively) that your code can be condensed to

```
forvalues x = 1996/2016 { 
    gen count`x' = event_`x'0101_`x'0401 + event_`x'0401_`x'0701 + event_`x'0701_`x'1001 + event_`x'1001_`x'0101
}
```

given that local macros `i` and `x` run over the same values. (Those are macros in Stata's sense.) But I would not start there.

As you say, the data are wide format (I prefer the term layout as less overloaded), so the main job is not to write loops at all, but to `reshape` to long. This example embodies a little guesswork and shows some technique. Absent a data example to work with, I first create a sandbox:

```
clear 
set obs 21
local y = 1 
foreach v in yyyy0101_yyyy0401 yyyy0401_yyyy0701 yyyy0701_yyyy1001 yyyy1001_yyyy0101 { 
    gen `v' = `++y' 
}
gen year = 1995 + _n 

rename (yyyy*) (count#), addnumber 

reshape long count, i(year) j(quarter) 

gen qdate = yq(y, q) 

egen ycount = total(count), by(year) 
egen qcount = total(count), by(quarter) 
gen half = cond(inlist(quarter, 1, 2), 1, 2)
egen hcount = total(count), by(year half) 

list if year < 1998, sepby(year) 

     +------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | year   quarter   count   qdate   ycount   qcount   half   hcount |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 1996         1       2     144       14       42      1        5 |
  2. | 1996         2       3     145       14       63      1        5 |
  3. | 1996         3       4     146       14       84      2        9 |
  4. | 1996         4       5     147       14      105      2        9 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------|
  5. | 1997         1       2     148       14       42      1        5 |
  6. | 1997         2       3     149       14       63      1        5 |
  7. | 1997         3       4     150       14       84      2        9 |
  8. | 1997         4       5     151       14      105      2        9 |
     +------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How does this differ from what you did, as you already used `reshape long`? Principally to underline that whatever totals you want on different time scales can be generated in place. You don't need repeated `collapse` or different versions of the same dataset. How to tabulate, list or otherwise deal with the repetitions would be different questions.

Comment: The problem is with `reshape long count, i(year) j(quarter)`. By editing the variables, I can get the dates to convert to `19950100` for 1995-Q1 or `19950400`  for 1995-Q2, etc. I don't know how you got from the reshape to the output table you are showing. When I do it, STATA doesn't seem to understand  `j(quarter)`.

Comment: My code is self-contained and reproducible. You need to show us your code and then we can comment. "does not seem to understand" is not an error I can diagnose. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve